# Random Variable with E and V

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

Question is Let X be a random variable with $E(X)=1$ , $V(X)=5$.

I need to find (a) $E[(1+X)^2]$ and (b) $V(4+3X)$.

I think I solved (b) alright. Please let me know if there is an error.

For (b), I used definition of variance $V(aX+b)=a^2*V(X)$.

So in this case, it would be $V(4+3X)=3^2*V(X)= 45$.

How can I solve (a)? I know $E[(1+X)^2]$ is $E[1+2X+X^2]$ so I can break it down to $E[1]+E[2X]+E[X^2]$. What to do next?

Comment: 1. Please see the [self-study tag wiki info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 2. Write down the quantities you know and the quantities you need to find. Do you know any relationships between what you need and what you have?

Comment: It's useful to know that $E[X^2] = V(X) + E[X]^2.$